# does any one see how i can make this more effiecient?

Tags: php

so my code works but its not very fast when i have a $id with a large amount of applicationID's and im afraid that that table will just grow and grow.

```
$x = '0';
$y = '0';
$query0 = "SELECT applicationID 
   FROM app
   WHERE schoolID='$id'";
$result0 = mysql_db_query($aidDB, $query0, $connection);
while ($r0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0)) {
    $query = "SELECT App_Last, App_First, applicationID
     FROM applicant
     WHERE (App_Last IS NOT NULL OR App_First IS NOT NULL) AND applicationID='" . $r0['0'] . "'"; //echo $query;
    $result = mysql_db_query($aidDB, $query, $connection);
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //$temp_array[$x][0]=$r[2];//appid*/
        $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT applicationID 
    FROM OrderTrack
    WHERE applicationID='" . $r['2'] . "'"; //echo $query1;
        $result1 = mysql_db_query($aidDB, $query1, $connection);
        while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            $temp_array1[$y][0] = "<option name=appid value=\"" . $r1['0'] . "\">" . $r['1'] . "," . $r['0'] . "</option>";
            $temp_array[$x][0] = $r1[0]; //appid cause it to count the distinct amount on customer names may need to change to appid
            $x ++;
            $y ++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please, describe the tables and their relations. Looks to me like you could join them.

Comment: well im using the app table to get the application Id based on schoolID so that it cuts down on the number of ApplicationID's it has to go through. . then i select the app_fisrt app_last of the applicant in the applicant table based on the application id pull from the app table. the last query takes the applicationid of the aplicant and loocks the ordertrack to see it there is a record. if there is it creates an <optiom>. the app table is the only table that has a schoolID feild all the tables do however have a applicationID which is the same across the board

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could remove the excess curly brace at the end. That would change the script from not running to running ;)

You should also consider using prepared statements to fix the SQL Injection attack vectors in your query. Also, you might be able to use a JOIN for fetching the data in one go instead of three.

Another suggestion would be to separate the HTML building and fetching from each other. That wouldnt make it more efficient, but more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Nested queries are never a good way to code. They are, as you found, are slow. If you can pull out the data in one query, which you should be able to, this will vastly improve your codes speed / efficiency.

An example, untested obviously.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT applicationID, App_Last, App_First 
FROM app a 
  JOIN applicant ap ON a.applicationID = ap.ApplicationID 
  JOIN OrderTrack ot ON a.applicationID = ot.applicationID 
WHERE (ap.App_Last IS NOT NULL OR ap.App_First IS NOT NULL) AND a.schoolID = '$id'";
```

This way you should only have 1 query for all of that, which means 1 loop, and 1 query pulled from the MySQL server. Hopefully that query works, if not trying and re-trying it should help it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite 3 queries into 1.
`$query = "SELECT DISTINCT app.applicationID, a.App_Last, a.App_First

   FROM app ap

   INNER JOIN applicant a ON (a.applicationID = app.applicationID AND App_Last IS NOT NULL OR App_First IS NOT NULL)

   INNER JOIN OrderTrack o ON (o.applicationID = a.applicationID)

   WHERE ap.schoolID='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'`
Now you need just 1 loop and 1 call to `mysql_db_query`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do some joining....

try something like:
Select DISTINCT applicationId from app INNER JOIN applicant ON applicant.applicationID=app.applicationID INNER JOIN OrderTrack ON applicant.applicationID=OrderTrack.applicationID WHERE App_Last IS NOT NULL OR App_First IS NOT NULL AND schoolID={id}

....and then loop your result set

WARNING: As I just whipped this up real quick, I didn't create the tables and test. Also, the naming conventions are a bit odd and I cant see your entire tables....but this should work unless i've made an egregious logic error.

Comment: im attempting it but seems that somewhere theres a naming mistake and i get #1109 - Unknown table 'app' in field list  when i run the statement. im not to sure why you are using ap in the from feild

Comment: with your statement i get #1052 - Column 'applicationID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: good point...just change it to 'SELECT DISTINCT app.applicationId'. As far as the table 'app', I was basing that on the table selected from in $query0 of your question code.